# session management in server application

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, session, server

i am developing a server application of building rest web services in java using spring-hibernate,where this service will be used by other clients.i have followed this link http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/08/spring-restful-web-services.html.

my question here is

1>should i maintain session in server application?if yes how?

2>should i do any validation in server side?

3>To validate user while login  should i use spring security for that or just comparing username and password in database is enough?

4>when user doesnot interact with server for particular time there should be session timeout ,should this be implemented in sserver application or client side?

i am very new to java and web service,any suggestions,links and guidence are appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> 1>should i maintain session in server application?if yes how?

Web-services are `stateless` means server does not store any state about the client session on the server side.You should manage the session on the client side, other wise you will end-up handling an heavy load of sessions on the server side and I am sure you don't want to do that.

> 2>should i do any validation in server side?

If by validation you mean data integrity, I think you will have to do it for the favor of data integrity and your application well being.

> 3>To validate user while login should i use spring security for that
>   or just comparing username and password in database is enough?

You can do both, using spring security is a good choice , and you will have to configure or build your own `AuthentificationManager` which will compare credentials withe those stored in the database

> 4>when user doesnot interact with server for particular time there
>   should be session timeout ,should this be implemented in sserver
>   application or client side?

You can set a session timeout , and this should be implemented on the client-side.

Comment: here validation means using "@valid" annotation in model and what does dataintegrity mean.is it needed

Comment: @allDroid data integrity, means passing coherant correct data to your database, For example if you have a field that shouldn't be null, You have to make sure that it isn't null before trying to persist it.

Comment: if application has to be used via in internet and intranet .is there anything i should do in server application part for this to work?or how could i make  my application to Work only in intranet and only in internet for some process.

Comment: @allDroid that's a DNS configuration, You set an Apache Server and some network configuration.

Answer (score 0):

*1>should i maintain session in server application?if yes how?*

Rest web services do not depend on client session since they are stateless, so there is no need to think about session management.

*2>should i do any validation in server side?*

What kind of validation?

*3>To validate user while login should i use spring security for that or just comparing username and password in database is enough?*

You can use both, but I think a token based authentication (Based on spring security) will be the best way.

*4>when user does not interact with server for particular time there should be session timeout ,should this be implemented in server application or client side?*

Since server does not keep track of user session, timeout should be implemented on client side.

You can check the following project if you want its a excellent starting point.

https://github.com/dhavaln/spring-rest-boilerplate